# How do I write a rules file for Blockify?

Tags: packaging

There are no Debian packages available for the Blockify ad-muter for Spotify and I would like to build one. I have created copyright, compat, and all other Debian package files for it, except a working rules file. I know to build and install Blockify from its source code one merely runs:

```
sudo pip3 install git+https://github.com/serialoverflow/blockify
```

but I do not know how to turn this into a rules file's `build:` function.

Answer (score 0):

As I've tested building package (Didn't install it), the new way, which is documented in Debian, working just fine:

```
#! /usr/bin/make -f

#export DH_VERBOSE = 1
export PYBUILD_NAME = blockify

%:
        dh $@ --with python2,python3 --buildsystem=pybuild
```

**Reference:** [Debian Packaging: Python LibraryStyleGuide](https://wiki.debian.org/Python/LibraryStyleGuide?action=show&redirect=Python%2FPackaging#Style_Guide_for_Packaging_Python_Libraries)